# Xpath syntax when ' and / are present in the text

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have an XPath expression that contains both a `'` and `/`. What is the correct way to write this?

```
a[.="what's in/out"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends where your XPath expression appears. The way you have written it

```
a[.="what's in/out"]
```

is fine as far as the XPath specification is concerned. But if you try to write it like this in a Java string literal then you'll have to escape the double quotes with backslashes:

```
callXpath("a[.=\"what's in/out\"]");
```

and if you try to write it in an XML attribute delimited by double quotes it will have to be

```
select="a[.=&quot;what's in/out&quot;]"
```

while if you try to write it in an XML attribute delimited by single quotes it will have to be

```
select='a[.="what&apos;s in/out"]'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael

Comment: @swathi9, SO protocol is not to say thanks, but rather to mark an answer as accepted, which you can do by clicking on the "tick-mark" next to the answer.

Comment: .Sorry about that.Very new to Stackoverflow. Learning new things.

Answer (score 1):

You can use escape character `\`:

`a[.="what\'s in/out"]`

Comment: got it! Thanks @Mesut.

Comment: @swathi9 you may give an up. Thanks